# Is Clojure / Java interop slow?

Tags: clojure

Is calling Java from Clojure slow in comparison to pure Clojure code? And is this because there is always reflection under the hood? Thanks.

Comment: No, and no. (Correctly done interop calls are not slow, and there is *not* always reflection under the hood).

Comment: Keep in mind that as Java is Clojure's runtime, if all calls into Java involved reflection, absolutely anything/everything Clojure did would be slow, because *everything* is Java at the bottom. Calls into `clojure.lang.RT` are typically done through the same mechanisms as anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Not really.  You can generally write java interop code in clojure that is exactly as fast as equivalent java code, including type hints to eliminate reflection. Generally that means its more low level, much more verbose and *faster* than idiomatic clojure.